# Building a land bridge across the Bering Strait

Tags: structural-analysis, bridges, tunnels

Would building a land bridge across the Bering Strait be more cost effective then building an actual bridge or tunnel? Much like how the Chinese build artificial islands in the South China Sea.

Comment: Did you mean "[Bering Strait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bering_Strait)"?

Comment: Capitals matter!

Comment: @Transistor the original was "bearing straight", so not just capitals ;)

Comment: How about lowering thew water level? wasn't it originally a land bridge?

Comment: My guess is that ice bergs and ice sheets would be a problem . Ignoring the politics.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking a 50 mile/80 km straight would be troublesome at best, ecologically disastrous at worst.

Realistically, large spans like this would tend to be a combination of bridge, land bridge, tunnel, and artificial islands, each according to navigation, ecology, and cost.

Comment: In addition to this, if we failed to curb global warming & the Arctic polar ice cap were to melt, such a land bridge would impinge of a "Northwest Passage" style shipping route between Europe & Asia, via the Arctic seas.